# How to override configuration in Android application?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences, activity-lifecycle

**Solved** (solution at the bottom)

In my activity I need to read preferences and then override configuration. In constructor Context is not ready yet:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

In `onCreate` it is too late:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getResources() has already been called

Quote from *ContextThemeWrapper* [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#applyOverrideConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration)):

> This [*applyOverrideConfiguration*] method can only be called once, and must be called before any calls to getResources() or getAssets() are made.

**What is the right time and place to override configuration?**

Code excerpt from my current *working* solution below.

```
class OverrideActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    private boolean __overrideConf = false;

    @Override
    public Resources getResources() {
        if (!__overrideConf) {
            // ...
            // read shared preferences needs context
            // ...
            applyOverrideConfiguration(configuration);
            __overrideConf = true;
        }
        return super.getResources();
    }
}
```

**Solution** (override protected method [attachBaseContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#attachBaseContext(android.content.Context)))

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    applyOverrideConfiguration(new Configuration());
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution** (override protected method [attachBaseContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#attachBaseContext(android.content.Context)))

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    // copypaste safe code
    applyOverrideConfiguration(new Configuration());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution helped me solve an issue where changing language was not working in Android 7 & below, after implementing Dagger Hilt.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading to appcompat 1.2.0 solves the issue with java.lang.IllegalStateException: getResources() has already been called.
Replace the appcompat dependency app level build.gradle with this

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
}
```